# display push notifications with Codenameone

Tags: java, notifications, push-notification, codenameone

I'm a beginner with Codename One; I don't know how can I send push notifications and display a theme. I'm using this code:

```
public class PushDemo implements PushCallback {

    private Form current;
    public void init(Object context) {

     }
     public void start() {
         if(current != null){
             current.show();
             return;
         }
        new StateMachine("/theme");
     }

     public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
     }

     public void destroy() {

     }

     public void push(String value) {
        Dialog.show("Push Received", value, "OK", null);
     }

     public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
        Dialog.show("Push Registered", "Device ID: " + deviceId + "\nDevice Key: " +Push.getDeviceKey() , "OK", null);
     }

     public void pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) {
        Dialog.show("Registration Error", "Error " + errorCode + "\n" + error, "OK", null);
     }

}
```

Comment: Added the Java tag for syntax highlighting

Comment: Have you checked this video out yet? https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a walkthru of push here: 
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-6.html

First you need to set the following constants to actually register/send the push:

```
private static final String PUSH_TOKEN = "********-****-****-****-*************";
private static final String GCM_SENDER_ID = "99999999999999";
private static final String GCM_SERVER_API_KEY = "******************-********************";
private static final boolean ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH = false;
private static final String ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH_CERT = "https://domain.com/linkToP12Prod.p12";
private static final String ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH_CERT_PASSWORD = "ProdPassword";
private static final String ITUNES_DEVELOPMENT_PUSH_CERT = "https://domain.com/linkToP12Dev.p12";
private static final String ITUNES_DEVELOPMENT_PUSH_CERT_PASSWORD = "DevPassword";
```

You are missing the register call which should go in the end of your start() method:

```
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    // registering for push after the UI appears
    Hashtable args = new Hashtable();
    args.put(com.codename1.push.Push.GOOGLE_PUSH_KEY, GCM_SENDER_ID);
    Display.getInstance().registerPush(args, true);
});
```

Then you can send a push to a device using something like this:

```
Push.sendPushMessage(PUSH_TOKEN, textToShowToTheUser + ";" + hiddenPayload,
                ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH, GCM_SERVER_API_KEY, cert,pass, 3, pid);
```

Comment: thank you, now when i send a push, this notification is not shown in the second device

Comment: Its a push to a single specific device. If you want to send push to all devices your server will need to loop thru the devices in batches of 500 and send the push based on the device keys.

Comment: I have to activate something else that Cloud Messaging för Android ?
In the documentation there is : _Push notification is only enabled for pro accounts in Codename One_

Comment: You need a pro account. You also need to activate GCM and APNS and generate the proper certificates to APNS the chat tutorial linked above goes thru all the steps

Comment: I want to test push noifications just with android, so I think it's not necessary to have a pro account, is not it ?
I activated GCM, when i send a push message i don't receive any notification by the other devices, do you have any suggestion please ?!

Comment: You need to use our push servers not GCM and yes a pro account is necessary for our push support